# What is better to get and store Location frequently - Service or BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, service, location, broadcastreceiver

I have a confusion between Service and BroadcastReceiver. I am working on a Location-based app. In this, I want to store user's location into database whenever there is a significant change in his/her location(eg. 10 meters).

I am using LocationListener for it and it is working fine. But my dilemma is : where to write the onLocationChanged() method - In the onReceive() method of BroadcastReceiver or in a Service?

And if I am using a Service, then in which method of Service , shall I write the below code?

Here is my Location Listener:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(location != null){
                //Code to populate location-data into the database table.
            }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
      };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5, 10, locationListener);
```

Can anyone please suggest me what is the better way to implement it? I have read all the Android Developer Docs about both Service and BroadcastReceiver , but I am still not able to differentiate between their usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it depends on how much work you want to do.

If you want to do something small when you receive a broadcast, then you can do it in `onReceive()` method of your `BroadcastReceiver`. BUT, `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread. So, Android OS will kill it if it takes too long.

Thus, if you want to do something that might take a while, you should do it in `Service` on a background thread. As it was suggested, you can put your code in the service's `onStart()` method. Don't keep the service running if it does not do anything (waist of battery and other resources). Start service every time you receive a broadcast and finish it as soon as it has completed the assigned job.

P.S. Mark L. Murphy (aka CommonsWare) has several excellent books about Android development. Google Busy Coder's Guide Android Development.

**UPDATE:**

About your desire to cancel your background task when your applications goes to background.

Consider what you will do if your background task is interrupted in the middle. You need to handle this situation. If you are OK with that, then you can use either `AsyncTask` or `Service` to do your task in background. Your choice again depends on your task's size and type.

`AsyncTask` is generally intended to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread. Android documentation [suggests](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that tasks for `AsyncTask` should not exceed few seconds. On the other hand, `Service` is designed to perform long operations without communications with UI.

About canceling. `AsyncTask` will be canceled when your activity is finished as it is tired to the UI thread. To stop service you will need to call [`stopService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService) from your activity.

As you need to store location information frequently, you can start service when you activity starts, communicate with it making use of the service's `onBind()` method, and then stop your service in the `onPause()` method of your activity.

Comment: Thanx Nikolai, its a great explanation. So are you trying to say that I should put the above code in a background thread i.e. AsyncTask ?

Comment: Depends))) Do you want to make sure that the device will not go to sleep while you service runs? This is not a good thing to do (you should let the OS do power management) but if you are absolutely sure that this service is essential...

Comment: I want my service to run only when my app is in foreground. If the app goes in background , I stop this service. Is that good?

Comment: And I saw your profile on Stack Overflow . Great work dude. I appreciate it being an android developer :) Best of luck.

Comment: Is it your app's design (run service only when app is in foreground) or you just want to save battery? I mean, do you want to make sure that your background process doesn't run when app is not in foreground?

Comment: Its kinda both of them. Its in my design and I want to save battery as well.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your purpose. If you want to catch the location in the background, use in Service.

BroadcastReciever's onReceive method will call only when what action you registered to receive.

If you want to do in Foreground, you can simply use it in the Activity. But when your activity is closed, you can't get the locations.

So, you decide according to your functionality.

Comment: +1 from me . So in a Service, in which method shall I write the above code?

Comment: Write your code in onStart method. Dont forget to finish the service. It will keep on running until you call finish() method.

Comment: And where should I finish the Service? In every activity?

Comment: Whenever you want your app to stop getting user location.. but keep in mind that location detection drains the battery so you might do this judiciously

Answer (score 2):

Services are used to run your code in background, are used mainly to download, music play.. after the user puts the app in background(presses home or back button).
`BroadcastReceivers` are used to receive messages sent through `sendBroadcast()` method and are used to catch system notifications like Bluetooth, internet availability, get messages from other apps...

I think you want to use Services here because `BroadcastReceiver` can't help you to listen a location change if the app is in background.

Comment: But I want to do the above things only when my app is in foreground?

Comment: That it depends on what you actually want.. I don't recommend you to keep the service running all the time since the location pooling is a pretty good way to drain the device battery..